# What do you call the event when a person says "ahhhhhhmm..."?

Tags: interjections, discourse-markers, filler-words

One of the person here keeps on saying those words, I want to say that he needs to avoid that but I can't describe it.

Example:

> **Me**: Please example the following to me.
>
> **Him**: That object is the result of *aaaaa*.... and actually by merging that one and this it will result in *aaahhmm.*.. (What do you call that?)
>
> **Me**: Okay!

How do you describe those *aaaaa....* and *aaahhhmm..* moments?

Comment: Verbal pause? Maybe

Comment: Just tell him/her stop aaaaa, uuuu, eeee all the time.